# How to set value in ngModel in onChange?

Tags: angular

I am using CDAC Typing Script in Angular8 code, when i select language  we could able to write in that specific language, but when I want to save in DB angular NgModel it is not bind/set in that specific language.Anyone please suggest me how to fix this issues.

```
 <input id="easy-input-{{ word }}" name="easy-input-{{ word }}" class="easy-word form-control word-input textarea-multilang col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 mt-2"  type="text" ngModel>
```

THIS IS MY CONSOLE OUTPUT

My expected output should be like this:

```
{easy-input-Dog: "boy", dificult-input-Dog: "good", easy-input-man: "bad", dificult-input-man: "nice", easy-input-help: "poor", }
dificult-input-Dog: "boy"
dificult-input-help: "good"
dificult-input-man: "bad"
easy-input-Dog: "nice"
easy-input-help: "poor"
easy-input-man: "great"
```

===================================================================

But I got like this :

```
{easy-input-Dog-hidden: "", dificult-input-Dog-hidden: "", easy-input-man-hidden: "", dificult-input-man-hidden: "", easy-input-help-hidden: "", …}
dificult-input-Dog: ""
dificult-input-help: ""
dificult-input-man: ""
easy-input-Dog: ""
easy-input-help: ""
easy-input-man: ""
```

Difficult and easy are input box where I wrote in any specific language.After that I want to save all data in databases but it will not save in database. Front-end i am using Angular8 NgModel will not bind data.This my problem.

NOTE: All these input boxes generate automatically according to words.

Comment: can you please reproduce code on stackblitz ? it gives more idea about your problem/

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview (you forget [(ngModel)]="variable")

Comment: It does't work showing undefined    @Eliseo

Comment: please provide a [mcve] there is not enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @SumitKumarRoy, read the docs. You need decided if you want to use Reactive Forms (Then you need create a formGroup and add in your inputs formControlName divective) or Template Driven form (then you create an object and use [(ngModel)]). This is the way to relational the "model" (the variables in your .ts) and the "view" (the input tags in your .html)